# Google Cloud Python library for BigQuery - fetch_data returns records out of order

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the Google Cloud client library to import records from a BigQuery table into my Python program. The table is large and the records are in a particular order such that I need to stream them in order for algorithmic reasons. The following code returns an iterator that produces the table records out of order.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField

gcclient = bigquery.Client()
dataset = gcclient.dataset("dataset_name")
gcschema = [
          SchemaField('field1', 'STRING', mode = 'required'),
          SchemaField('field2', 'STRING', mode = 'required'),
          SchemaField('field3', 'STRING', mode = 'required'),
          SchemaField('field4', 'STRING', mode = 'required'),
          SchemaField('field5', 'STRING', mode = 'required')
]
gctable = dataset.table("table_name", gcschema)
it = gctable.fetch_data() # Iterator is not in the order of table records
```

Is there a way to configure this request so the records will be returned in the order of the BigQuery table, or is there another way to stream ordered records one by one?

Comment: If you need a particular order for the rows, you need to execute a query that uses `ORDER BY` on a particular column. BigQuery reorders rows in its internal storage to increase the efficiency of reading from tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elliott said in a comment - rows in a SQL table have no particular order, other than the order you can ask for when querying the data.

If an algorithm needs the data sorted in any particular order, the table needs to have a column to be used to get data in that desired order.